# How secure is my encryption with password script? (Golang, AES256, pbkdf2, hmac)

Tags: security, encryption, go, aes, kdf

First, I want to say that this is just an learning exercise and I do not intend to use this in production.

I wrote a small application in Golang with two functions: `encrypt(plaintext string, password string)` and `decrypt(encrypted string, password string)`

The encryption steps are:

1. Generate random 256 bits to use as salt
2. Generate 128 bits to use as an Initialization Vector
3. Use PDKDF2 to generate a 32 bit key from the password and salt
4. Generate an 32 bit HMAC with the key and plaintext, and append it to the beginning of the plaintext
5. Encrypt the hmac+plaintext with AES in CFB mode

The returned byte array looks like this:

```
[256 bit salt] [128 bit iv] encrypted([256 bit hmac] [plaintext])
```

When decrypting:

1. Extract the salt and use it with the provided password to compute the key
2. Extract the IV and decrypt the encrypted portion of the ciphertext
3. Extract the mac from the decrypted value
4. Validate the mac with the plaintext

I'm not crazy enough to use my own encryption script in any production projects, so please point me to any libraries that do this for me (simple password / message encryption that is relatively secure)

Here is the source code to the two functions:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "crypto/hmac"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/pbkdf2"
)


const saltlen = 32
const keylen = 32
const iterations = 100002

// returns ciphertext of the following format:
// [32 bit salt][128 bit iv][encrypted plaintext]
func encrypt(plaintext string, password string) string {
    // allocate memory to hold the header of the ciphertext
    header := make([]byte, saltlen + aes.BlockSize)

    // generate salt
    salt := header[:saltlen]
    if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, salt); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // generate initialization vector
    iv := header[saltlen:aes.BlockSize+saltlen]
    if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // generate a 32 bit key with the provided password
    key := pbkdf2.Key([]byte(password), salt, iterations, keylen, sha256.New)

    // generate a hmac for the message with the key
    mac := hmac.New(sha256.New, key)
    mac.Write([]byte(plaintext))
    hmac := mac.Sum(nil)

    // append this hmac to the plaintext
    plaintext = string(hmac) + plaintext

    //create the cipher
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // allocate space for the ciphertext and write the header to it
    ciphertext := make([]byte, len(header) + len(plaintext))
    copy(ciphertext, header)

    // encrypt
    stream := cipher.NewCFBEncrypter(block, iv)
    stream.XORKeyStream(ciphertext[aes.BlockSize+saltlen:], []byte(plaintext))
    return string(ciphertext)
}

func decrypt(encrypted string, password string) string {
    ciphertext := []byte(encrypted)
    // get the salt from the ciphertext
    salt := ciphertext[:saltlen]
    // get the IV from the ciphertext
    iv := ciphertext[saltlen:aes.BlockSize+saltlen]
    // generate the key with the KDF
    key := pbkdf2.Key([]byte(password), salt, iterations, keylen, sha256.New)

    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if (err != nil) {
        panic(err)
    }

    if len(ciphertext) < aes.BlockSize {
        return ""
    }

    decrypted := ciphertext[saltlen+aes.BlockSize:]
    stream := cipher.NewCFBDecrypter(block, iv)
    stream.XORKeyStream(decrypted, decrypted)

    // extract hmac from plaintext
    extractedMac := decrypted[:32]
    plaintext := decrypted[32:]

    // validate the hmac
    mac := hmac.New(sha256.New, key)
    mac.Write(plaintext)
    expectedMac := mac.Sum(nil)
    if !hmac.Equal(extractedMac, expectedMac) {
        return ""
    }

    return string(plaintext)
}
```

Comment: note that codereview.stackexchange.com is a thing

Comment: http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: Also are you actually encrypting the password? Because if so, that's a relatively terrible idea if all you need is validation. If not, 1Password has fairly extensive specs on how they do it.

Comment: Typically encryption is not used for passwords -- there is no need to be able to retrieve the plaintext -- in fact, that's a negative.  Typically you do: `V = Hash(SALT, PASSWORD)` and save V & SALT.  Then when it comes time to verify, you recompute `V2 = Hash(SALT, MIGHTBEPASSWORD)`.  Then if V2 == V, the password was correct.  The tricky bit is making sure that `Hash()` has all the cryptographic properties you want it to have.

Comment: I'm not encrypting or storing the password. I'm storing the random salt and the IV unencrypted in the ciphertext, and the key is recomputed using the salt with the provided password at the time of decryption.

Comment: My idea of storing the HMAC in the encrypted portion of the ciphertext is to authenticate the plaintext as well as to validate its integrity

Comment: @pvg Also, what are the benefits of using bcrypt over pbkdf2? It seems like most sources suggest that pdkdf2 > bcrypt

Comment: Which sources? PBKDF2 should only be used where you require it due to specifications (e.g. satisfying FIPS/NIST requirements). bcrypt is much harder to parallelize, and (as per my answer) scrypt is harder again. RE: authenticating the plaintext: you should authenticate the ciphertext, in which case you should use AES-GCM (https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/cipher/#NewGCM) to do it in one pass.

Comment: @DesmondLee bcrypt has the more foolproof, simpler API, in its typical implementations. For most purposes, the debates about the advantage of one over the other are rather theoretical, when in doubt, use bcrypt. If you can derive the plaintext of the password, then yes, you are storing the password. Short of writing a password manager, you should not do that since it tends to have the security of storing the password in plaintext.

Comment: @pvg I think I am misunderstanding. I can't derive the plaintext of the password. The user is providing it to decrypt the message.

Comment: An attacker could—without having to run any rounds of bcrypt/scrypt—by testing a bunch of passwords from a password dump. You're storing `[32 bit salt] [128 bit iv] encrypted([32 bit hmac] [plaintext])` - AES decrypt operations on modern CPUs are *very* (very) fast.

Comment: ok, is this question really about encrypting/decrypting a message, using some key derived from from user supplied secret? because that's a somewhat different question and you've awoken the hounds by saying 'password encryption'.

Comment: pvg: Yes, that's what this question is about. I realized that my wording in the title is the cause of the misunderstanding. Thanks

Comment: The answer to that one is probably 'use NaCl'. If it's about real-time messages, use OTR.

Comment: 32 bit salt, 32 IV and 32 bit HMAC all seem too small to provide any meaningful security. You probably meant bytes, right? Otherwise, you really should increase those numbers.

Comment: Yes, I got bits/bytes mixed up in my question. I corrected the mistakes in the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Note**, since the question was about encrypting messages rather than passwords: If you're encrypting small messages rather than hashing passwords, Go's [secretbox](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/nacl/secretbox) package—as part of its NaCl implementation—is the way to go. If you're intent on rolling your own—and I strongly recommend against it, unless it stays within your own dev environment—then AES-GCM is the way to go here.

Otherwise, most of the below still applies:

1. Symmetric encryption isn't useful for passwords. There should be no reason why you need the plaintext back—you should only care about comparing hashes (or, more precisely, derivative keys).
2. PBKDF2, compared to scrypt or bcrypt, is not ideal (10002 rounds, in 2015, is probably a bit low too). scrypt is memory-hard and much harder to parallelize on a GPU, and in 2015, has had a sufficiently long life as to make it safer than bcrypt (you would still use bcrypt in cases where the scrypt library for your language wasn't great).
3. MAC-then-encrypt [has issues](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac) - you should encrypt-then-MAC.
4. Given #3, you should use AES-GCM (Galois Counter Mode) over AES-CBC + HMAC.

Go has a great [bcrypt](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt) package with an easy-to-use API (generates salts for you; securely compares).

I also wrote an [scrypt](https://github.com/elithrar/simple-scrypt) package that mirrors that package, as the underlying scrypt package requires you to validate your own params and generate your own salts.

Comment: I'm confused about #1, because I don't believe I am encrypting the password (unless my understanding of what I am doing with the HMAC part is incorrect)

I'm storing the generated salt and using the PBKDF2 in the decryption stage to obtain the key. The reason I MAC then encrypt is to prevent an adversary from giving invalid ciphertexts. I'll look into MAC-then-encrypt vs encrypt-then-MAC to gain a better understanding.

Also, I'm confused about the sentence about not needing the plaintext back. Isn't that the point of decryption?

Comment: As per your post, you're storing `[32 bit salt] [128 bit iv] encrypted([32 bit hmac] [plaintext])` — which shows you encrypting the password. Further, if an adversary is giving invalid ciphertexts, it doesn't matter: the HMAC exists to help you validate it (by running HMAC over the ciphertext and constant-time comparing both HMACs).

Comment: Decryption does give you the plaintext back, but ask yourself: why do you need it? Why does everyone else recommend bcrypt/scrypt instead of some kind of strange PDKDF2 + HMAC-SHA-256 + AES-CBC construction?

Comment: My original question title might have caused some confusion about the purpose of my script. It's not for encrypting passwords, but for encrypting a message with a user supplied password. The supplied password is used along with the saved salt to generate the symmetric key with PBKDF2. But from your answer it seems like PBKDF2 is weak against brute force attacks, and I should use bcrypt/script instead. It also seems like I should use AES-GCM instead of AES-CBC/HMAC-SHA-256. Is that correct?

Comment: In which case you should use AES-GCM (only) or (better still) Go's NaCl implementation, which uses Salsa20 & Poly1305 to encrypt messages with a shared key: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/nacl/secretbox

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answers

Comment: @DesmondLee No problems. I've added mention of secretbox & AES-GCM to the accepted answer for posterity as well.

Comment: @elithrar it's probably worth removing the stuff about passwords (or maybe swapping the order), since it turned out the thing is really about key derivation and encryption rather than password validation or storage, which is what it confusingly looked like initially.

Comment: @elithar What would I use to encrypt larger amounts of data? (like journals, articles, etc)

Comment: How large are we talking? secretbox is still OK for that, otherwise AES-GCM.